# Get all the combinations of a vector of vector. into a new Vector

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

i'm trying to extract all combinations of int from a vector of vectors. So I used the function found in an other topic :

```
void Phrase_Structuration::printAll(const vector<WORD_AND_TYPE> &allVecs, size_t vecIndex, int strSoFar)
{
    if (vecIndex >= allVecs.size())
    {
        cout << "FINISHED POSSIBILITY : ";
        cout << strSoFar << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i<allVecs[vecIndex].types.size(); i++)
        printAll(allVecs, vecIndex + 1, strSoFar + allVecs[vecIndex].types[i]);
}
```

The problem is I don't wan't to print the additions of the possible solutions, but I wan't it in a new vector:  **vector < vector < WORDS_TYPE> >** .

WORD_AND_TYPE is a structure of a string and an enumeration (which is an integer).

WORDS_TYPE is the enumeration name.

So the output atm is :

68

74

74

I desire to put each part of the addition in a new vector like :

vector.at(0) = { 29, 29, 10 }

vector.at(1) = { 35, 29, 10 }

vector.at(2) = { 29, 35, 10 }

etc etc..

If anyone can help me, that'll be awesome as the recursion is kind of new for me. If you have any questions, do not hesitate

EDIT :

I've done this, but this does only the half part of the work (it doesnt give every possibilities)...

```
void Phrase_Structuration::printAll(const vector<WORD_AND_TYPE> &allVecs, vector<WORDS_TYPE> &tmpVector, vector<vector<WORDS_TYPE>> &phraseWordsTypesVector, size_t vecIndex, int strSoFar)
{
if (vecIndex >= allVecs.size())
{
    cout << "FINISHED POSSIBILITY : ";
    tmpVector.clear();
    cout << strSoFar << endl;
    return;
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < allVecs[vecIndex].types.size(); i++)
{
    //cout << "Vec : " << vecIndex << endl;     
    tmpVector.push_back(allVecs[vecIndex].types[i]);
    printAll(allVecs, tmpVector, phraseWordsTypesVector, vecIndex + 1, strSoFar + allVecs[vecIndex].types[i]);
    tmpVector.push_back(allVecs[vecIndex].types[i]);

    phraseWordsTypesVector.push_back(tmpVector);        
//  cout << "Vector : " << vecIndex << endl;
}
```

}

EDIT 2 : Here is a screenshot of the current output : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=904380basicoutput.png

Comment: I don't have a clue how the output you are currently generating relates to the result you want.  Note that it would be very helpful if you showed a minimal input.

Comment: Added a screen in the edit

Comment: Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: I've done this with next permutation :

https://paste.ofcode.org/67NTfVaGLeKHdYhHRim2ir

But it seems to only reorder the vectors in the vector, without links between them. 

Here is my output :http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=353939basicoutput.png (I know, my painting skill is awesome...)

Comment: Here's the full code : https://github.com/hach3/Artificial-Intelligence-Semantic-Objects-based.-Console-Application-with-TTS/blob/master/NaturalLanguageProcessingv0.1.0/Language/Phrase_Structuration.cpp (starts line 50) in case it can help